# What is equivalent of C# casting to char in PHP?

Tags: c#, php, .net

I have a very short C#. class which I've nearly completely converted to PHP.

The the below lines of code are preventing me from completing the conversion, as PHP does not have a `(char)` typecast?

```
// string[] source; 
// int step;
char ch1 = (char) (source[i] + step);
ch2 = (char) (source[i + 1] + step);
```

source is a string and step is an int.

Maybe?

```
$ch1 = (string) ($source[$i] . $step);
$ch2 = (string) ($source[$i + 1] . $step);
```

Please bear in mind, I have not coded/used C# before - so I am just going off my PHP knowledge when converting.

Comment: what type is source and step, it won't be string concatenate it looks like its taking an int/byte adding  the integer value then converting the result to a char

Comment: @BobVale in the Visual C#.NET class - source is a string and step is an int

Comment: OK its taking the char at index i, treating it a a number (ie the ascii value) and adding step to the value and then converting the value back to a char eg if the string was "ab" step was 1 and i was 0 then ch1 would be 'b' and ch2 would be 'c'

Comment: I've updated title to reflect what you trying to do (generally "convert from XXX to YYY language" questions are not welcome, so specific title is better). Feel free to revert.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$ch1 = chr(ord(substr($source,$i,1)) + $step);
$ch2 = chr(ord(substr($source,$i+1,1)) + $step);
```